# How to update image captions in Word 2007 after you add new ones?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, image-editing, cross-reference, page-layout-view

I can work with Image captions, they are added fine in the doc.

But when I add new ones in the middle, the captions are not updated and I end up having two or more captions having the same number.

How do I update the references?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what's happening is that your new captions are automatically numbered, but the references to them are not automatically updated. There are a couple of ways to handle this. The first is easiest, but you have to remember to do it.

- Press Ctrl-A to select all the text in the document.
- Press F9

If you want the fields to be correct before printing but don't care about it until then there's an option to update the fields before printing.

- Click the application button
- Click Word Options
- Select the Display category
- Tick the *Update fields before printing* check box

Selecting Print Preview or Print will update all the references in the document.

Answer (score 0):

In MS Word 2007, at least the one I'm using, they're updated automatically. Upon inserting the third picture in the middle of "Picture 1" and "Picture 2", the "Picture 2" becomes "Picture 3" and the inserted one takes the caption of "Picture 2".

However, I may be misunderstanding the question. Is that what you're asking ?

Comment: That doesn't happen for me. I have to right click the references in the text and choose update.

Comment: @Pentium10 - Where exactly do you click update ?